# DuplicateMappingException while converting Inheritence strategy from InheritanceType.JOINED to InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Problem: I have a legacy application containing one abstract super class (lets say `Task`) and more than 50 subclasses called as `SubTask1` and so on. Further, these subclasses have various fields which have same name like `filename`, `user` etc. Moreover, these subclasses are having various @ManyToOne relationships with one class (Lets say `Property`).

Now, as an ORM tool, we are using `hibernate` with inheritance strategy as `JOINED`. Now, query performance for these entities is very bad. Hence, to improve performance, I am trying to change the inheritence strategy to SINGLE_TABLE and letting hibernate to generate the schema.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
abstract public class Task {
    public String type;

    //Getters and setters
}

@Entity 
public class SubTask1 extends Task {
    public subTask1Field;
    public String user;
    public string filename;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Property host;
    //Getters and setters

}

@Entity 
public class SubTask2 extends Task {
    public subTask2Field;

    public String user;
    public string filename;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Property host;
    //Getters and setters

}

@Entity
public class Property {
    @Unique
    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    public String value;    
}
```

Issue: During application start-up, I am getting below exception.

```
2020-07-09 12:18:26,665 ERROR --- [                     main] play                           :   Can't start in PROD mode with errors
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:204)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:616)
        at play.Play.start(Play.java:538)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:309)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:160)
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [Task] contains logical column name [fileName] referenced by multiple physical column names: [`filename`], [`fileName`]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl$TableColumnNameBinding.bindLogicalToPhysical(Configuration.java:3021)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl$TableColumnNameBinding.addBinding(Configuration.java:3008)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addColumnBinding(Configuration.java:3053)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.addColumnBinding(Ejb3Column.java:330)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.linkWithValue(Ejb3Column.java:322)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.linkWithValue(SimpleValueBinder.java:361)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.make(SimpleValueBinder.java:336)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2166)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:895)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:728)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3625)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3579)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1381)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:918)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
        at play.Play.start(Play.java:568)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:309)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:160)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:204)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:616)
        at play.Play.start(Play.java:538)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [Task] contains logical column name [fileName] referenced by multiple physical column names: [`filename`], [`fileName`]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl$TableColumnNameBinding.bindLogicalToPhysical(Configuration.java:3021)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl$TableColumnNameBinding.addBinding(Configuration.java:3008)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addColumnBinding(Configuration.java:3053)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.addColumnBinding(Ejb3Column.java:330)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.linkWithValue(Ejb3Column.java:322)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.linkWithValue(SimpleValueBinder.java:361)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.make(SimpleValueBinder.java:336)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2166)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:895)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:728)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3625)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3579)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1381)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:918)
        ... 6 more
```

Questions :

1. is it even possible to convert inheritence strategy like this without making changes in my Entity classes? If yes, what are the changes will you suggest on this?
2. Is there any other way to improve query performance here? whenever I am trying to fetch `Task` entity, it creates a join on all `SubTask` tables with each `SubTask` table having joins with `Property` table.

Comment: You are using inheritance why are you duplicating fields anyway? Does not make sense even with JOINED. The performance of JOINED and SINGLE_TABLE does not varry. You must have another performance issue. Did you check the generated SQL?

Comment: Yes i agree with duplicating fields problem. Its not an ideal way to design it. But since its a legacy app, i cant do anything about it. Further, these classes are big, i can't even venture on consolidating common fields in superclass. And yes, i have seen the generated SQLs. They are more than 600 lines of sql generated containing joins between all tables. What i feel is, if i change inheritance type, all those joins will not be there.

Comment: Yes but all data will be on the same database table. And you say you cannot change the legacy app. With SINGLE_TABLE you will have to change the database model

Comment: Yes database i am willing to change. There won't be any other way. i want minimal change in java code. As of now, i have only changed one line i.e. change inheritance type on superclass.

Comment: So the answer is: as long as you have duplicate attributes in you classes there is no way to make it work

Comment: But this answer suggest something else. Although they do not have duplicate class attributes but they are mapped to same column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646960/can-i-reuse-a-column-across-subclasses-in-a-hibernate-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance-strategy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217517/discussion-between-simon-martinelli-and-manish-bansal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is [`filename`], [`fileName`] You have the same attribute writen with different cases.

Comment: Thank you Simon. Luckily, it was just one subclass with this 1 conflict.